# SiteMap RootNode, get all child nodes where rootnode = "Home"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I wanted to write if/for each statement that will get me all the child node where the rootNode = "home"

this is what i have so far

```
 if (topLevelNode.Title == "Home")
 {
     var topLevelNodes = SiteMap......
 }
 foreach (SiteMapNode node in topLevelNodes)
 {
     ...........................
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (topLevelNode.Title == "Home")
 {
     var result = topLevelNode.ChildNodes;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if (topLevelNode.Title == "Home")
 {
     var topLevelNodes = topLevelNode.ChildNodes
 }
 foreach (SiteMapNode node in topLevelNodes)
 {
     //Do-What you want to the siteMap file
 }